# Create a dropdown list displaying users meta data

Tags: user-meta

I want to display a `dropdown` list of users using information from the `wp_usermeta` table. I know that there is a method `wp_dropdown_users` that outputs a `select` list of users but I can't figure out how to modify the code in order to allow me to display a column from my `meta` table.

Can anyone help me out?

Currently I've modified `wp_dropdown_users` but it only outputs a list displaying `options` like this `()`.

```
function wp_dropdown_users( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'show_option_all' => 'Choose Grower to Share...', 'show_option_none' => '', 'hide_if_only_one_author' => '',
        'orderby' => 'display_name', 'order' => 'ASC',
        'include' => '', 'exclude' => '1', 'multi' => 0,
        'show' => 'display_name', 'echo' => 1,
        'selected' => 0, 'name' => 'user', 'class' => '', 'id' => '',
        'blog_id' => $GLOBALS['blog_id'], 'who' => '', 'include_selected' => false
    );

    $defaults['selected'] = is_author() ? get_query_var( 'author' ) : 0;

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    $query_args = wp_array_slice_assoc( $r, array( 'blog_id', 'include', 'exclude', 'orderby', 'order', 'who' ) );
    $query_args['fields'] = array( 'ID', 'user_login', $show );
    $users = get_users( $query_args );

    $output = '';
    if ( !empty($users) && ( empty($hide_if_only_one_author) || count($users) > 1 ) ) {
        $name = esc_attr( $name );
        if ( $multi && ! $id )
            $id = '';
        else
            $id = $id ? " id='" . esc_attr( $id ) . "'" : " id='$name'";

        $output = "<select name='{$name}'{$id} class='$class'>\n";

        if ( $show_option_all )
            $output .= "\t<option value='0'>$show_option_all</option>\n";

        if ( $show_option_none ) {
            $_selected = selected( -1, $selected, false );
            $output .= "\t<option value='-1'$_selected>$show_option_none</option>\n";
        }

        $found_selected = false;
        foreach ( (array) $users as $user ) {
            $user->ID = (int) $user->ID;
            $_selected = selected( $user->ID, $selected, false );

            if ( $_selected )
                $found_selected = true;
            $display = !empty($user->$show) ? $user->$show : '('. $user->user_login . ')';
            $output .= "\t<option value='$user->ID'$_selected>" . esc_html($display) . "</option>\n";
        }

        if ( $include_selected && ! $found_selected && ( $selected > 0 ) ) {
            $user = get_userdata( $selected );
            $_selected = selected( $user->ID, $selected, false );
            $display = !empty($user->$show) ? $user->$show : '('. $user->user_login . ')';
            $output .= "\t<option value='$user->ID'$_selected>" . esc_html($display) . "</option>\n";
        }

        $output .= "</select>";
    }
```

Comment: Did you modify the core function? You should avoid doing edits to core files. Did you check out the `wp_dropdown_users` filter?

Comment: Yes I changed the core function in `users.php`. No I was not aware of this filter?

Comment: It's like "attacking windmills" to edit core files after each upgrade ;-) So the preferred way is to modify things via hooks (actions/filters) to avoid loosing the custom modifications after each upgrade.